# CodeIgniter controller not interpreting hyphen correctly in function call

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-2

I'm having an odd problem.  My controller is trying to call uri segments and is not interpreting the hyphen correctly.  I don't get any error.  Just the rest of the page beyond the call doesn't render.  This is for a CMS and I have created an edit_market function in my markets controller.  I want to be able to call the page content for a page, which is referenced in the database by the page navigation name, which is sometimes hyphenated (consumer-goods, for example).

Here is my controller:

```
function edit_market($page=NULL) {

// Send copy and images to page
$data['query'] = $this->markets_materials_model->get_content('markets', $page);

... load view ...
```

My markets_materials_model:

```
function get_content($table, $category) {
    $this->db->where('navigation', $category);
    return $this->db->get($table)->result();    
}
```

This works fine for all links that don't have a hyphen, but fails when the link has a hyphen.  What is causing this?  The only way I can edit these pages right now is by using edit_market in my URI rather than being able to create a route that has "edit-market" in it.  I believe if I remember right that accessing controllers directly was a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using the controller name: not sure where it came about that it is a bad practice.

Comment: Something I heard on NetTuts.

Comment: Ah. Quite odd. Routes are supposed to be used to pretty up your urls if you want to do stuff in ways your controller is not already hooked up for. But mandating that you MUST use routes and must not use controller methods really defeats the convention over configuration principle.